# How to change password via API using Devise Token Auth? Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, access-token

I am trying to change the password of a user, using Devise Token Auth gem. But there are parameters that I do not know if it is good since I extract them from the database. Specifically, from the Tokens column of my users table.

This is my request with their respective headers, according to what the documentation tells me:

```
PUT /auth/password HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
token-type: Bearer
access-token: $2a$10$d6b2GP5N3WT4/fR62S1VL.kiLx9w0YA6Rb5aVYQtXMBPImLx9ix2i
client: -Z2_wBWzH1GHiAjCAaHAKA
expiry: 1509654584
uid: my@email.com

password=123456789&password_confirmation=123456789
```

This is the token column of my user table that corresponds to my user with the email `my@email.com`:

```
{
    "oJ7t-1kXUFsde9J_euKuZA":{
        "token":"$2a$10$cYAP0ZVndFJz9JUK4tvoOuc96k/JBtgmSyn0cmwvWwy0o.J0XOtKW",
        "expiry":1509642442,
        "last_token":"$2a$10$Boy8Yp2Znb0uOS9tt/3KYum7PX/Jjmb.Igzo5GUs4tDRCejDU5bya",
        "updated_at":"2017-10-19T12:07:22.356-05:00"
    },
    "-Z2_wBWzH1GHiAjCAaHAKA":{
        "token":"$2a$10$d6b2GP5N3WT4/fR62S1VL.kiLx9w0YA6Rb5aVYQtXMBPImLx9ix2i",
        "expiry":1509654584,
        "last_token":"$2a$10$qFTq5JqGUBXayXODsKUSROjjw.TrFYVGtf.EEULCzRWIhMa79ycZS",
        "updated_at":"2017-10-19T15:29:44.204-05:00"
    }
}
```

But, the result of my request always I get **401 Unauthorized**.

I'm using the second json object, where the key I put as a client parameter and the token attribute, I put it as my access_token parameter in my request via PUT.

Am I doing my request correctly with the parameters I have set? O How do I get the client and access-token parameters?

Comment: Then what happen ?
How did you solve it ?

Comment: Any luck solving it Dvex?

Answer (score 3):

It does not answer exactly the question about the 401 Unauthorized error but here is what I did according to [the documentation page](https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage). Set the `config.check_current_password_before_update` to `:password` which means that if the user wants to update his password, he needs to give his current password as well.

Check your `rails routes` for the correct path. Mine was : `PUT /auth/password/`

Then in the body of your request :

```
{"current_password":"old_password","password":"new_password","password_confirmation":"new_password"}
```

---

About the 401 Unauthorized error, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085385/1805275), maybe this is due to your user authentication.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could help you, the **documentation** includes the [following infos](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr)

> Account updates. This route will update an existing user's account settings. The default accepted params are password and password_confirmation, but this can be customized using the devise_parameter_sanitizer system. If config.check_current_password_before_update is set to :attributes the current_password param is checked before any update, if it is set to :password the current_password param is checked only if the request updates user password.

[image]

So I wonder, do you have to include this in your devise **strong params** declarations for the [edit action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)?

But still there is no explanation that it is returning a **401 Unauthorized**.

> [401 Unauthorized (RFC 7235)
>   Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and Digest access authentication.[33] 401 semantically means "unauthenticated",[34] i.e. the user does not have the necessary credentials.
>   Note: Some sites issue HTTP 401 when an IP address is banned from the website (usually the website domain) and that specific address is refused permission to access a website.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)