# Rails: Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error, but I don't know why. I specifically exclude CSRF checking. The `#webhook` method works, even in production. Other similar questions are about Devise, but I'm not using Devise in this controller.

`stripes_controller.rb`

```
class StripesController < ApplicationController
  Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_PRIVATE']
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:webhook, :create]
  
  def show
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = params[:amount]
  
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )
  
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Membership Fee',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )
  
    render :show
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to stripe_path
  end
```

`routes.rb`

```
resource :stripe do
```

`Log`

```
Started POST "/stripe/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-03 11:58:17 -0500
Processing by StripesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"amount"=>"100", "stripeToken"=>"tok_1BgFZ2IYOmXNPhc121HxNtw0", "stripeEmail"=>"test@example.com"}
  Rendering stripes/show.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered stripes/show.haml within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (2.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3533ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-03 11:58:21 -0500
```

Rails is by default on `:debug` log level. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

I was able to reproduce it by setting

`devise.rb`

```
config.timeout_in = 1.minute # 8.hours
```

It works fine if I am logged in and active, but if the session times out, then it causes this 401 problem.

This is the request/response from the browser. It shows a success and 302 response, not 401. It says 401 in the server console log though.

```
POST /stripe/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 82
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://localhost:3000/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

There isn't a single 401 response in the browser network log, even sorted by status, even with Preserver Log.

Rails 5.0.2

Comment: What is in your `application_controller`?

Comment: We're gonna need to see the _whole_ of `StripesController#create`, including any `before_action`/`after_action` callbacks and `ApplicationController` actions that affect it/are affected by it.

Comment: you might be having authenticate_user before_action in application controller.

Comment: @MarekLipka Here is the [application_controller.rb](https://pastebin.com/XF9uUmy5). However, no before_actions access the user.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I added whole `#create`, but it doesn't access the user. There are no `before_action` or `after_action` callbacks.

Comment: It's funny that `stripes/show` is being redirected, it seems it in fact doesn't stop on any `before_action`. Could you show also `stripes/show.html.haml`?

Comment: @MarekLipka Here is [show.haml](https://pastebin.com/wQ522CxF)

Comment: I do use `if user_signed_in?` in the layout `application.haml`, but it doesn't  cause a redirect or authentication error.

Comment: Ok, but what happens if you try to remove this check? And the second question: Do you have any user record with id of `1`?

Comment: @MarekLipka I can access public pages with the template fine without being signed in. I do have a user with id 1. See update.

Comment: @Chloe I don't have a clue then - you may want to use this gem to trace this mysterious DB query:
https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tracked the problem down to `user_signed_in?` as suggested by Marek. That function will **HALT** execution and issue a 302 redirect, while printing a 401 in the server log!

`devise.rb`

```
config.timeout_in = 1.minute # 8.hours
```

`stripes_controller.rb`

```
class StripesController < ApplicationController
  layout false
```

`show.haml`

```
%h2 Thank you!
%p 
  Your payment of 
  %strong= number_to_currency(@amount.to_i * 0.01)
  has been received.
- if user_signed_in?
  Signed in
- else
  Signed out
```

If the user is signed in, the page will load fine. If the user's session expires, then **Devise will redirect and set a flash message**!

`log`

```
Started GET "/stripe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-03 14:39:08 -0500
Processing by StripesController#show as HTML
  Rendering stripes/show.haml
  User Load (22.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered stripes/show.haml (179.2ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 399ms (ActiveRecord: 52.0ms)


Started GET "/stripe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-03 14:39:09 -0500
Processing by StripesController#show as HTML
  Rendering stripes/show.haml
  Rendered stripes/show.haml (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 219ms (Views: 99.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

[image: chrome network log]

I couldn't find a way to check if the user is logged in without redirecting.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails+devise+%22user_signed_in%22+stop+redirecting&ia=qa

`user_signed_in?` isn't even in the Devise API documentation when you search the methods! I was hoping there was an optional argument.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise

So I set `layout false` so it stops using `application.haml` which contains `user_signed_in?`. I wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 12):

HTTP code 401 Unauthorized is for authentication (https://httpstatuses.com/401). It is not related to CSRF. In that case it would raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken.

I'am pretty sure you have a before_action in your ApplicationController that requires user authentication (or in routes.rb, or in the config of nginx/Apache).

Comment: Here is [application_controller.rb](https://pastebin.com/XF9uUmy5), but it doesn't require user authentication. I only authenticate in certain controllers.